# file copy in scala play

Tags: scala, playframework

i am to copy a file in scala But getting FileNotFound error, The assets folder is in the same directory where is src:

```
val src = new File("/assets/public/images/default/male.jpg")
val dest = new File("/assets/public/images/profile/male1.jpg")

new FileOutputStream(dest) getChannel() transferFrom(
new FileInputStream(src) getChannel, 0, Long.MaxValue )
```

Comment: Are you _absolutely_ sure that these are the absolute paths to the files?

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are trying to copy the file using [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29), which requires a valid path to the existing file else it'll throw `FileNotFoundException`. (see the doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File%29))

```
val src = new File("/assets/public/images/default/male.jpg")
val dest = new File("/assets/public/images/profile/male1.jpg")
new FileOutputStream(dest) //dest should exist
```

Nevertheless, Play has its own utility to **copy** files. Here is the [link](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.Files%24).

```
import play.api.libs.Files
Files.copyFile(src, dest, true, true)
println(dest.getAbsolutePath())  // filepath of copied file
```

Also, since the files get copied to the working directory, you might not be able to see the new file in the folder structure of your favorite IDE.

Aside, you may get the path for public assets by using `routes`

```
val srcPath = routes.Assets.at("public/images/default/male.jpg").url
```

Comment: Link gets malformed on SO editor.. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.Files$

Answer (score 0):

### A general advise

When copying files on Java, use the [`FileUtils.copy(...)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) from the Apache commons project.

### For your specific problem

You get "File not found" if the file cannot be found by the running process. This could be because your file is indeed not there or because the process is lacking rights to see the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is a little ambiguous, it seems you meant to give paths relative to the current working directory.  That means that this code should be executed from a directory which contains the `assets` directory.  If this is so, then you have made a mistake and given absolute paths to your file objects, not relative ones.  All you have to do is remove the initial forward slash from those paths and it should work.

As it is, you are telling Scala/Java to look in the root directory for `assets`.